# Visual Studio Code on Windows 7 - window has no borders

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm running VS Code on Win 7 with aero off and the Win 7 "Basic" theme. I'm using the VS light theme on VSCode. This means that editor windows and such have a white background. Apps that obey the Win 7 theme has a boundary around them to delineate where the window ends. VSCode doesn't appear to obey this -

[image]
Notice how the window just bleeds into the window behind it. I find this visually disorienting. Yes, a different theme with a dark background would solve this, but I have a strong preference for dark text on a light (white) background.

Is there any way to force VSCode to use the Win 7 windows layout?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

VSCode will use the OS standard window decorations, including window frame borders, if you set the "Window: Title Bar Style" setting to "native".  (It affects more than just the title bar.)

Comment: TYVM.  Spent 2 hours trying to get a border around my VSCode windows using window.activeBorder (which no longer works), installing the Peacock theme, messing with Windows themes but never made this last connection to set it to "Native"
I run on Windows 10 (and this works)